# How to show message before buy when user has in OG group and product SKU?

Tags: commerce, rules

I have a small problem with Drupal commerce rules. I want to achieve showing message before buy a product with a specific SKU and when the user is a member of a specific OG group (whose group is created by a node age group).
But I don't know how to configure rules to check user OG group id and product sku.

My rule, export is below:

```
{ "rules_only_one_purchase" : {
    "LABEL" : "Only One Purchase",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "og", "rules_i18n", "commerce_cart" ],
    "ON" : { "commerce_cart_product_add" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "entity_is_of_bundle" : {
          "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item" ],
          "type" : "commerce_line_item",
          "bundle" : { "value" : { "product" : "product" } }
        }
      },
      { "AND" : [
          { "og_entity_in_group" : {
              "entity" : [ "site:current-user" ],
              "group" : [ "site:og-context--node" ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "LOOP" : {
          "USING" : { "list" : [ "site:current-user:og-membership" ] },
          "ITEM" : { "list_item" : "Current list item" },
          "DO" : [
            { "component_rules_check_user_og_group" : {
                "loged_user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
                "user_og_membership" : [ "list-item" ]
              }
            },
            { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "Test message." } }
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Please add an explanation about what you think your current rule is doing. also, if you want something to happen for a specific SKU, where in this rule is there anything about the "specific SKU" (as in your question). Also, the "AND" construct in your Rules Conditions seems not right: an condition like "a AND b" makes sens, but in your rule it looks like " AND b" (the 'a'-part of such AND condition is missing, that cannot be right I think). Also, that "node age group", where in the rule is there anything about that? Also is it "Test message" that should be shown before buy a product?

Comment: this is a crosspost with http://stackoverflow.com/q/44042573/4640431